# how to add buttons for yes/no type answers and give a specific answer based on input in dialog flow console?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

i have created my intents and entities using dialog flow and using it with python.
I want to add  an feature that has buttons for  yes/no question in the dialog flow console.I have explored through wit.api and  dialog flow.dialog flow  is easier to use than wit api. i have found that we can use integrations and implement that but that has limited functionality

Answer (score 3):

Button type rich message is referred to as “Suggestion Chips” by Google Assistant and “Quick Replies” by Facebook messenger.

Go to Dialogflow console, select the intent and scroll down to Responses. Click on “Google Assistant” to see the list of support rich messages.

Select "Suggestion Chips" and enter yes, no options in that.

[image]
[image]

If you are using webhook fulfillment code, then pass the custom payload for suggestion chips through the code.

For more details, refer to https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/rich-message-button-response-dialogflow-chatbot/

Answer (score 1):

The platforms Dialogflow supports each provide different UI features. For example, the Actions on Google platform supports [Suggestion Chips](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion-chip), which you could easily make use of for "yes" or "no" suggested answers:

[image]

You can do so from Dialogflow's UI by first adding the platform you want to support, in the Response section of the Intent screen:

[image: Actions on Google response]

[image: Actions on Google response]

and then adding the relevant response type with the "Add Message Content" button, in this case "Suggestion chips":

[image: Suggestion Chips]

[image: Suggestion Chips]

To handle each answer, just create a follow-up intent that matches its value.